# How to capture category name and id from one page and use that data in another page to send ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am moving to another page using the following code

```
<a v-bind:href="'http://search?category='+post.name">{{post.name}}</a>
```

In search page(the redirected page) I need to get this post.name in order to send the ajax request. I am getting values only from api. Is there any way to store the data and pass it to the other page. I am a beginner and it will be helpful if somebody help me..

Also I have a doubt .. How to pass service also along with category using v-bind.. Please have a help to solve the same

Comment: use window.location.search in another page to get URL query parameter

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if any issues.